# Port requirements for a Full-Node?

Tags: nodes, port-numbers, firewalls

Do I need to open BOTH TCP and UDP 30303 on my router? Or only TCP?

EDIT: I am also unclear if the UDP protocol should be opened on Port 30301 instead (as discussed on this page: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/enode-url-format).

EDIT: I am really just looking for settings for a default Wallet running to support the network. What protocols and what ports need to be permitted through my firewall to be running a full node fully supporting the Ethereum network?

EDIT: I was able to get a clear answer from the Devs on which ports and protocol should be opened if you want to run a full-node:

"Peer discovery is UDP only. This means that on 30303 you are using both TCP (ETH and LES protocols) and UDP (old peer discovery for finding ETH peers), on 30304 only UDP is used."

What this means is that these ports need to be opened on your firewall:

-- Port 30303 (TCP and UDP)

-- Port 30304 (UDP)

Comment: This may be a duplicate of that question. However, that question does not appear to have a definitive answer.

Comment: Read the very first sentence of the other answer please.

Comment: check if your router supports upnp: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Connecting-to-the-network

Comment: I am stuck with a U-verse Giga Power router (1000 Mbs service), but it does not support upnp.I read the first sentence of the other answer (Ethereum clients use a listener (TCP) port and a discovery (UDP) port, both on 30303 by default.) And also the last sentence: (I think this misunderstanding is spreading also because of the behavior of the bootnode util. In fact, it uses 30301 as default UDP discovery port.) They seem to contradict each other.

Comment: I got a clear answer from the devs. it differs from what was in the duplicate question. I believe this should be made public and easily accessible to anyone wanting to run a Full-Node for Ethereum.

Comment: I reopened your question, please take the time to convert your last edit to an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Devs provided a definitive answer on which ports and protocols should be opened if you want to run a full-node:

Quoted from discussion, "Peer discovery is UDP only. This means that on 30303 you are using both TCP (ETH and LES protocols) and UDP (old peer discovery for finding ETH peers), on 30304 only UDP is used."

**What this means is that these ports need to be opened on your firewall:**

**-- Port 30303 (TCP and UDP)**

**-- Port 30304 (UDP)**

Comment: Do we need both inbound and outbound UDP port discovery to work, or only outbound is sufficient?